# Don't know how to count event times by SQL

Tags: sql

### Summarize the problem

I am a new one to learn SQL, I meet an issue from my tutorials. The background is In order to record the information of vending machines in a city, count the closing of vending machine doors and compare with the door design life, the data structure in the database is shown below. Data is collected at regular intervals by the built-in sensors.

### Part of table:

| Index | Machine ID | Signal Upload Time | Door Status | Fan Status | Region | Date Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 00001 | 08/20/2021 15:57:48 | closed | run | City A | 2021/08/20 |
| 1 | 00001 | 08/20/2021 15:59:06 | opened | closed | City A | 2021/08/20 |
| 2 | 00001 | 08/20/2021 16:00:22 | closed | run | City A | 2021/08/20 |
| 3 | 00002 | 05/10/2021 09:14:32 | closed | run | City B | 2021/05/10 |
| 4 | 00002 | 05/10/2021 09:15:02 | closed | run | City B | 2021/05/10 |
| 5 | 00002 | 05/10/2021 09:17:12 | opened | closed | City B | 2021/05/10 |
| 6 | 00003 | 08/03/2021 11:44:02 | closed | run | City A | 2021/08/03 |
| 7 | 00003 | 08/03/2021 11:45:52 | opened | closed | City A | 2021/08/03 |
| 8 | 00003 | 08/03/2021 11:47:17 | opened | closed | City A | 2021/08/03 |
| 9 | 00004 | 04/12/2021 22:44:44 | closed | run | City B | 2021/04/12 |
| 10 | 00004 | 04/12/2021 22:47:04 | opened | closed | City B | 2021/04/12 |
| 11 | 00004 | 04/12/2021 22:52:11 | opened | closed | City B | 2021/04/12 |
| 12 | 00004 | 04/12/2021 22:56:59 | opened | closed | City B | 2021/04/12 |
| 13 | 00004 | 04/12/2021 23:00:22 | closed | run | City B | 2021/04/12 |

The amount of data is so large that there is no way to show it all. But from it we want to record the number of events like this.

| Index | Machine ID | Signal Upload Time | Door Status | Fan Status | Region | Date Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 00001 | 08/20/2021 15:59:06 | opened | closed | City A | 2021/08/20 |
| 2 | 00001 | 08/20/2021 16:00:22 | closed | run | City A | 2021/08/20 |

**The above data can indicate that in city A, the machine number 00001 happens to be opened and closed once (Event times add 1).** I want to count the number of such events occurring.

### The desired result I want

| Month | Region | Event times |
| --- | --- | --- |
| August | City A | xxx |
| September | City A | xxx |
| October | City A | xxx |
| ... | ... | ... |
| August | City B | xxx |
| September | City B | xxx |
| October | City B | xxx |

### Code I try

```
select Door Status, Date Time
from myfile
where Region = 'City A'
group by Date Time
```

I really don't know how to count event times, maybe I would be more easier just count "closed / opened" status. Many thanks. BR.

Comment: Please only tag your question with relevant product tag!

Comment: Try `select count(*) as total, .... etc` .